# cluster-mode SPARK refuses to run more than two jobs concurrently

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

My Spark cluster refuses to run more than two jobs simultaneously. One of the three will invariable stay stuck in 'ACCEPTED' state.

## Hardware

```
4 Data Node with spark clients, 24gb ram, 4processors
```

## Cluster Metrics show there should be enough cores

```
Apps Submitted    3
Apps Pending    1
Apps Running    2
Apps Completed    0
Containers Running   4
Memory Used    8GB
Memory Total  32GB
Memory Reserved  0B
VCores Used    4
VCores Total    8
VCores Reserved    0
Active Nodes    2
Decommissioned Nodes    0
Lost Nodes    0
Unhealthy Nodes   0
Rebooted Nodes    0
```

## On Application Manager you can see the final the only way to run the third app is to kill a running one

```
application_1504018580976_0002 adm com.x.app1 SPARK default 0 [date] N/A RUNNING UNDEFINED 2 2 5120 25.0 25.0 
application_1500031233020_0090 adm com.x.app2 SPARK default 0 [date] N/A RUNNING UNDEFINED 2 2 3072 25.0 25.0 
application_1504024737012_0001 adm com.x.app3 SPARK default 0 [date] N/A ACCEPTED UNDEFINED 0 0 0 0.0 0.0
```

The running apps have 2x containers and 2x allocated vcores, 25% of the queue and 25% of the cluster.

## Deployment command for all 3 apps.

```
/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/bin/spark-submit 
--master yarn 
--deploy-mode cluster 
--driver-cores 1 
--driver-memory 512m 
--num-executors 1 
--executor-cores 1 
--executor-memory 1G 
--class com..x.appx ../lib/foo.jar
```

## Capacity Scheduler

```
yarn.scheduler.capacity.default.minimum-user-limit-percent = 100
yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent = 0.2
yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications = 10000
yarn.scheduler.capacity.node-locality-delay = 40
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.accessible-node-labels = *
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.acl_administer_queue = *
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.capacity = 100
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_administer_jobs = *
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_submit_applications = *
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.capacity = 100
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.maximum-capacity = 100
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.state = RUNNING
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.user-limit-factor = 1
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues = default
```

Comment: You say 4 data nodes. But something is wrong. It says : VCores Total    8
And : Active Nodes    2

Comment: Hi Venkat , I have (6 boxes >> spark client on 4 boxes). Each box has 4 cores. What am I missing out here then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setting:

```
yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent = 0.2
```

Implies:

```
total vcores(8) x maximum-am-resource-percent(0.2) = 1.6
```

1.6 gets rounded up to 2 since partial vcores makes no sense. This means you can only have 2 application masters at a time which is why you can only run 2 jobs at a time.

Solution, bump up `yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent` to a higher value like 0.5.

Comment: That works! Thank you. I thought I changed that before already. Would "OverProvisioning work"? eg. 2.0% for a dev-platform. Or is 0.5 the absolute max setting? (ie: specifying 50% is 4AM cores // 8 cores=4AM cores + 4 executor cores)

Comment: You can specify 1.0 which implies 100%.  However, you could run the risk of a deadlock situation where only AMs are running and you have no vcores left for mappers or reducers to do work so setting it to 1.0 is not recommended.  Setting the `maximum-am-resource-percent` too low causes apps to queue (like your case) and you see `PENDING` apps.

Answer (score 0):

followings are parameters to control parallel execution are:

```
spark.executor.instances -> number of executors

spark.executor.cores -> number of cores per executors

spark.task.cpus -> number of tasks per cpu
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html